# dataitem.set not updating value in browser display kendo grid mvc

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid mvc with few number columns. columns are A,B,Total.
my grid in incell edit mode.
if i modify  A column cell value then i need to update value in Total column.
here my value is updating in javascript but its not displaying updated value in kendo grid browser view.

below is the code.

```js
 function onChange(e) {
        if (e.action == "itemchange" && e.field != "HoursYTD") {

            var editItemModelId = e.items[0].EmpNumber;
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataItem = grid.dataSource.get(editItemModelId);
            CurrentEditCell = e.field;
            var dataSource = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
            var _flt = { field: "EmpNumber", operator: "eq", value: editItemModelId };

            var copyDataSource = kendo.data.DataSource.create({
                data: dataSource.data()
            });
            copyDataSource.filter(_flt);

            const today = new Date();
            var currentMonth = today.getMonth()+1;

            var HoursYTD = 
                e.items[0].A +
                +e.items[0].B;

            dataItem.set("Total", HoursYTD);
            }
```

```html
columns.Bound(p => p.Total).Width(70).Filterable(false).Editable("function(dataItem) {return false;}").ClientFooterTemplate("#=kendo.toString(sum, '0,0')#").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "white-space: normal; text-align: center;font-weight: bold;" });
```